# Agora many to one live streaming

Tags: agora.io

I have a requirement in which different user will stream videos from their camera to a server and there will be dashboard in which the admin can view all the streams real-time something like how surveillance works? I think video broadcasting can help but the documentation says it enables live streaming from one-to-many and many-to-many but there is no mention of the many-to-one case. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The use-case you have described would be implemented the same way as a many-to-many broadcast.

For your use-case you would have all of the camera streams join the channel as *broadcasters* and then the "surveillance" user would join as an *audience*. The audience member subscribes to all the remote streams without having to broadcast a stream of their own.

**[Update]**
With Agora's SDK you can use an external video source, you would just have to manage it yourself. If you are using a custom video source then you don't need to use RTMP.

```
IVideoFrameConsumer mConsumer;
boolean mHasStarted;

// Create a VideoSource instance.
VideoSource source = new VideoSource() {
    @Override
    public int getBufferType() {
        // Get the current frame type. 
        // The SDK uses different methods to process different frame types.
        // If you want to switch to another VideoSource type, create another instance.
        // There are three video frame types: BYTE_BUFFER(1); BYTE_ARRAY(2); TEXTURE(3)
        return BufferType.BYTE_ARRAY;
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onInitialize(IVideoFrameConsumer consumer) {
        // Consumer was created by the SDK.
        // Save it in the lifecycle of the VideoSource.
        mConsumer = consumer;
    }

    @Override
     public boolean onStart() {
        mHasStarted = true;
    }

    @Override
      public void onStop() {
        mHasStarted = false;
    }

    @Override
     public void onDispose() {
        // Release the consumer.
        mConsumer = null;
    }
};

// Change the inputting video stream to the VideoSource instance.
rtcEngine.setVideoSource(source);

// After receiving the video frame data, use the consumer class to send the data.
// Choose differnet methods according to the frame type.
// For example, the current frame type is byte array, i.e. NV21.
if (mHasStarted && mConsumer != null) {
    mConsumer.consumeByteArrayFrame(data, AgoraVideoFrame.NV21, width, height, rotation, timestamp);
}
```

full guide: https://docs.agora.io/en/Video/custom_video_android?platform=Android

Comment: Ok, Thanks. I am actually streaming not directly from the camera but it is connected to an android app and the app streams the video using the RTMP protocol. In my case, the latency needs to be minimum as with WebRTC but I not have an option using it I have to rely on RTMP. Can I achieve low latency of 1-2 seconds or even less?

Comment: Are you using Agora or RTMP? RTMP has a 7sec latency (guaranteed) just how the tech is set up. If you use Agora's native protocols then you will see sub-second latency (250-750ms latency).

Comment: Yes, I am streaming using RTMP. The problem is Agora uses phones camera to live stream videos(correct me if I am wrong) but in my case, the live streaming is being done by a camera connected to the android app the camera renders the video on a Surface View and I want to live stream videos coming from the connected camera. Is it possible ?

Comment: You aren't restricted to use only the phone cameras, you can use any camera that is plugged into and recognized as a camera by the Android device.

Comment: @MayankRaj, I've updated my response to include how to use an external video source within Agora's SDK